# Why do I have trouble seeing files from Windows?

Tags: usb-connection-mode, windows, file-management

I have a Nook HD+ with `kivy` installed. When I connect the device with USB I can use Windows Explorer to see the directories and copy files to the Nook. But the log files it generates don't show up in Explorer. I've installed BusyBox so I can copy files around, and copying one of the logs to the base program directory works fine - `ls -l` shows that the permissions and owners are the same as the other files in the directory. But I can't see them from Windows.

I don't know which version of Android, if someone can tell me how to see it I'll add the information to the question.

Edit: shutting off the Nook and turning it back on seemed to clear things up. I don't know if it will show any new modifications to the directory, but I got what I needed for now.

Comment: What's the "base program directory"?

Comment: @DanHulme it's the subdirectory of `kivy` where I've stored the source files for my app.